# Inserting ads in HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html, google-dfp, google-ima

I want to insert ads in an HTML5 game using Google IMA SDK and DFP like [here](http://play.famobi.com/jewelish). I managed to display video ad following the [guide](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/) (even though it's for video content) and looking at how it's done in the game mentioned earlier. But I'm using sample ad tag from the guide:

```
http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x360&iu=/6062/iab_vast_samples/skippable&ciu_szs=300x250,728x90&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&correlator=[timestamp]
```

and not the ad tag generated in the DFP. If I insert it instead I get an error `The VAST response document is empty.`. Probably I messed up something, since I couldn't find any guide how to insert such ads from the beginning: where to sign up, how to generate tags and so on. I heard also that I must send to Google an example page for approval. Where? What page? 
It's all so confusing, tutorials are mostly irrelevant or outdated and I'm newbie at this, so I'm asking: is there any up to date guide about it, or could someone at least write what should I do step-by-step?

Answer (score -1):

If your using html5.

I would recomend using just using adsense code inside a Modal.
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/